# in rails, how could I send an email in an hour if certain condition get satisfied at that time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to send out an email as notification in an hour using active mailer. The email will be sent out if certain condition get satisfied. How could I achieve that? Is there any good example to study?

Comment: https://github.com/seomoz/qless

Comment: https://github.com/resque/resque

Comment: https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job

Comment: There are too many potential solutions for this issue - @bjhaid has provided some starting points but I'm voting to close this question as it is far too broad and does not show any research effort into a common problem. Also asking for examples or tutorials is off topic for StackOverflow.